# C Telling a header file about a struct in a c file without #including

Tags: c, struct, typedef

Bit of an odd problem here.

With a struct defined in one .c file, and another struct defined in a .h file, how can I let the .h file know about the struct in the .c (and visa versa), via another .h or .c. file IE: without being able to edit either file to include or redefine.

main.c:

```
typedef struct mystruct
{
    int whatever;
} Thing;

#include "header.h"
#include "otherHeaderThatIcanEdit.h"

otherstruct thisMethod()
{
    //returns an otherstruct
}
```

header.h:

```
typedef struct otherstruct
{
         float whatever;
} Stuff;

mystruct thisMethod()
{
    //returns a mystruct;
}
```

Comment: you cannot. you need to restructure your files.

Comment: If this is C code why are you defining functions in the .h?

Comment: This might be a case where you need to use pointers to structures and Forward Declaration. If your code only needs to know the size of a pointer then it does not need to have the struct definition. Just a forward declaration.

Comment: Also, looking at this since #include just pastes the include into the file, your header.h will have already seen the mystruct definition since the include follows it.

Comment: You should check your C book for how to use typedef with structs, and how struct tags work. You're using them backwards.

Comment: Generally speaking, you need to move the struct definition needed by the header file into that header file (or into a file it includes).    If the header file only needs to know about pointers to the struct type, then a forward declaration might be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you have provided the both structures are seen by both functions where those structure are actually used. But you should put before mystruct and otherstruct the keyword struct, like this:

```
struct otherstruct thisMethod()
{
//returns an otherstruct
}

struct mystruct thisMethod()
{
//returns an otherstruct
}
```

or if you cant modify those then you can write inside the file that can be modifyed the two following lines

```
typedef Thing mystruct;
typedef Stuff otherstruct;
```

note that the both functions have the same name, whish is an error.